# php re-create an array to new keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of keys and values. How can i recreate this array to make the second column as the key and 3rd column the values. Also remove all unwanted spacings.

```
Array
(
    [16] =>     hasKeyframes    : true
    [17] =>     hasMetadata     : true
    [18] =>     duration        : 30
    [19] =>     audiosamplerate : 22000
    [20] =>     audiodatarate   : 68
    [21] =>     datasize        : 1103197
}
```

New array should look like this.

```
Array
(
    [hasKeyframes] => true
    [hasMetadata] => true
    ...
}
```

Comment: just loop and assign new keys and values to a new array

Comment: How are you storing the key and values at the moment? Are they in two separate arrays? Can you provide the actual PHP code?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian it's the output of ffmpeg if I remember correctly

Comment: yes thank you @carlos. I wish people would answer the question rather then ask why the array looks like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
  $pair=explode(":",$value);
  $newArray[trim($pair[0])] = trim($pair[1]);
}
```

**EDIT**

> if we have something like [19] =>
>   Duration: 00:00:31.03, then we only
>   get 00 for $pair[1]

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
  $pair=explode(":",$value,2);
  $newArray[trim($pair[0])] = trim($pair[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shakti, this works, but what if we have something like     `[19] =>  Duration: 00:00:31.03`, then we only get 00 for `$pair[1]`

Comment: @Pinkie use third parameter of explode function rather than adding a space in explode: `$pair = explode(":", $value, 2);`

Comment: @Carlos: True, I was editing my answer for the same when you commented.

Comment: Yes, great one @carlos. I'll make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and works from PHP 5.3 because of the anonymous function used.

```
$array=array(/* ORIGINAL ARRAY */);
$newarray=array();

array_walk($array, function ($v, $k) use (&$newarray) {
    $pos=strpos($v, ':');
    $newkey=substr($v, 0, $pos);
    $newvalue=substr($v, $pos+1);
    $newarray[$newkey]=$newvalue;
});
```